# How can I transfer ASCII-files to the *console* of Picocom while being connected to a microcontroller

Tags: esp32, forth

*Setup*
Using a Linux PC.
Via picocom I am connected to an ESP32 board running ESP32Forth, which gives me a REPL (kinda console).

*Task to acchieve*
Since cut and paste is highly unreliable I need to transfer ascii-files in a way, that they are printed onto the console as they would be when cut'n'pasted.

How can I acchieve this?

I tried to use the lrz/lsz (send and receive files), but there are neither the sz/rz commands available on the microcontroller nor does the microcontroller has a filesystem. There is no OS running on the microcontroller (ESP32).

Comment: A few thoughts: try using a logfile, see "-logfile" option, or try setting the "-receive-cmd" to 'cat', which will just copy the input from the ESP32 to the output file. Or maybe try 'minicom' - maybe it has more options? It's been a long, long time since I used it. Have fun!